# multiple column display in JList 

Tags: java, swing, jlist

Is it possible to have multiple column display in JList ????

Comment: It depends on what you mean by [column](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html).

Comment: There's a cheat: If a monospace font is used, the widest entry of the left column could be measured, spaces could be filled in for every entry, so now you have quasi-columns.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a [JTable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) which is designed for this purpose.

Comment: Sorry, `JTable` is not designed for this purpose. `JTable` is designed for multiple columns that have distinct data in which all columns for that row are correlated. The OP is asking for a single list of values that can be listed in multiple columns to better take advantage of screen space, which is a different purpose.

Comment: @searchengine27 the OP "accepted" the answer so I think they know what they want better than you do.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether he accepted it or not, his question is literally not answered by your answer. He needs to revise his question to indicate what he meant where this answer is acceptable if that is the case. In it's current state, it does not answer his question.

Comment: @searchengine27, yes the question is answered. Your interpretation of the question is irrelevant, it is not your question. If the OP wanted to use a JList to better save screen space he could have "accepted" either of the other answers which show how to use wrapping. In any case it is NOT up to you to decide the intent of the OP's question. People have different levels of English and the OP indicated by accepting the answer that I understand the intent of his question.

Answer (score 13):

Absolutely! You need to make a call to setLayoutOrientation which indicates to the list how it should wrap its data before going to a new row. You can use JList.HORIZONTAL_WRAP or JList.VERITCAL_WRAP. This tells the data to be displayed as usual (as a list) and then wrap when it reaches the bottom.

If you want to combine that call with setVisibleRowCount(-1), you can then display as many items possible in the space that is available.

Answer (score 11):

To compare the two answers by camickr and JasCav:

- If you need multiple columns of data which somehow is linked together (like first column user name, second column icons of these users), a JTable is the right thing to use.
- If you simply want to use the screen space better by filling multiple columns of the same data, use the wrapping JList like described by JasCav.

Here is a wrapped JList of Icon objects:

[image: wrapped JList]

Here is a JTable with icons in the second row and a special TableCellRenderer:

[image: jTable]

(Both from [my current project](http://www.fencing-game.de/).)

Comment: Your 'current project' link links to an apache test page…